# How do I get the number of listitems that meet certain criteria?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I need for example the number of list-items, that are NOT "".
ATM, I solve it like this:

```
    public int getRealCount()
    {
        List<string> all = new List<string>(originList);
        int maxall = all.Count;
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < maxall; i++)
            {
                all.Remove("");
            }
        }
        catch { }
        return all.Count;
    }
```

No question, performance is pretty bad.  I'm lucky it's just a 10-items-list, but on a phone you should avoid such code.

So my question is, how can I improve this code?

One idea was: there could already be a method for that. The econd method would be: that all could be filled with only the items that are not "".

How should I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: maybe FindAll function of List is the best? trying it for performance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you want:

```
return originList.Count(x => x != "");
```

There's no need to create a copy of the collection at all. Note that you'll need `using System.Linq;` in your using directives at the start of your source code.

(Note that you should *not* have empty catch blocks like that - it's a *terrible* idea to suppress exceptions in that way. Only catch exceptions when you either want to *really handle them* or when you want to rethrow them wrapped as another type. If you *must* ignore an exception, you should at least log it somewhere.)

Answer (score 2):

If performance is your concern, then you should keep a collection that is only for these items.

If performance is not a big deal, I would suggest you use a Linq query on your collection. The cool thing about Linq is that the search is delayed until you need it.

```
int nonEmptyItemCount = originList.Count(str => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(str));
```

You could also do

```
int nonEmptyItemCount = originList.Count(str => str != "");
```

Comment: Count returns an int, not an `IEnumerable<string>`.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling all.remove("")  for every item in the list all.  Why not just call it once? You're not using i at all in your code...

Why not:

```
   public int getRealCount()
   {
        List<string> all = new List<string>(originList);

       int erased =all.RemoveAll(delegate(string s)
        {
            return s == "";
        });

        return all.Count - erased;
   }
```

Update:

Fixed the issue I had. This is without lambda's.

Answer (score 1):

You should use LINQ. Install ReSharper, it'll generate it for you.

Also, don't create an int maxall = all.Count and then use it in your for loop.

For mobile apps you shouldn't use unnecessary memory so just use all.Count in the for loop.